# Calculating average distance of many points using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, proximity

I have 30 points showing locations of petrol filling stations. I want to know the average distance of all the filling station to each other.

What tool can I use in ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: Qgis distance matrix calculate all distance between all features of your layer and can give you as output the average/standard deviation/min/max values if you choose this option.  What are you don't understand on this output ?

Comment: If you wish to also ask about QGIS please do that in a separate question.

Comment: Are the points in the same feature class?

Comment: Yea they are on thesame feature

Comment: What type of distance, euclidean distance (as the crow flies) or network distance (along roads)?

Comment: If you are wanting network distances do you have a Network Analyst license and the roads, etc to build a network dataset from?

Comment: Please provide any requested clarifications as an [edit] to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Up to ArcGIS 10.1 (which I use), there is a Near Tool that may allow you to accomplish what you are after. Please note that it seems to have been modified in more recent versions. This is the link to the Tool as of version 9 (http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?id=1111&pid=1107&topicname=Near_%28Analysis%29). If you feed your point shapefile both as input and near feature, for each point ArcGIS will calculate the distance to the nearest point and will report this in the attribute table. Then, you can use the distance field in the attribute table to calculate any statistic you are interested in (e.g., min, max, average).

Comment: While the OP didn't specify network distance, it's worth pointing out that the distance calculated by the Near Tool is euclidean distance and not distance along the roads.